# Pick string from xml using xpath?

Tags: xml, xpath

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:retrieveDetailsRequest>
    <serviceHeader>
        <version>1.0</version>
    <serviceHeader>
</ns2:retrieveDetailsRequest>
```

How can I pick string 'retrieveDetails' from this xml ?

That is from the main field element `ns2:retrieveDetailsRequest`, i need to pick only string 'retrieveDetails' and remove 'ns2:' and 'Request'.
(Tried substring functions but not working)

Appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `Unable to parse any XML input. The prefix "ns2" for element "ns2:retrieveDetailsRequest" is not bound.`

Comment: ns2 is namespace. Actually i need to know how to take a string from an element. <abcSTARefg> i need to pick STAR from this element.

Comment: I know that *ns2 is namespace*, but xml seems to be invalid for ideal parsing

Answer (score 0):

Worked with split function.
Explanation based on the above xml

## [xpath3("name(/*)")] gives  ns2:retrieveDetailsRequest

(stored this value in a variable named RootElement)

## [sessionVars.RootElement.split(':')[1]] gives retrieveDetailsRequest

(stored this value in a variable named RemoveNamespace

## [sessionVars.RemoveNamespace.split('Request')[0]] gives retrieveDetails

I tried this in Anypoint studio and worked fine. If you know any other simple way to pick this or know how to combine the split mentioned above, please suggest.